# Angular2 quickstart app no longer works after upgrade to rc2

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, vladivostok

I upgraded my angular2 app, which was based on the tutorial / quickstart app, from `rc1` to `rc2`.

`npm install` reports all is well:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

> typings install

typings WARN deprecated 6/2/2016: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 6/19/2016: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160613154055" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

├── core-js (global)
├── jasmine (global)
└── node (global)

├── @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/forms@0.1.0 
├── @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.7 
├── @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── @angular/upgrade@2.0.0-rc.2 
├── angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.12 
├── bootstrap@3.3.6 
<snip many more>
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
```

Before, it worked just fine. Now, when loading the first page, I'm getting a bunch of 404 errors:

```
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/http/http.umd.js
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/router-deprecated.umd.js
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/http/http.umd.js
[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/router-[1] 16.06.21 12:01:32 404 GET /node_modules/@angular/http/http.umd.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: some context: I upgraded because I wanted to use the new router, `3.0.0-beta.7`, which requires `rc2`.

Comment: Looks like you don't have it installed. Did you do a `npm install` after configuring your `packages.json`?

Comment: @rinukkusu I did. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have latest **systemjs.config.js** file. Below block is added few days back after RC2 release-

```
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
```

Comment: Yes, this was it! Unfortunately, I now get the same error from my highcharts dependency: `[1] 16.06.23 11:32:12 404 GET /node_modules/angular2-highcharts/dist/`. It used to work before the update. Sorry, I'm not familiar with SystemJS.

Comment: For highcharts error, In tsconfig.json, can you add exclude node modules like this-   "exclude": [
    "node_modules"]